# Reading a OneDrive local JSON file using fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, local, fetch-api, onedrive

I am trying to read a local JSON file using JavaScript. The file is in OneDrive however, and I am operating in Codepen. In the browser console, I get a 404 error.

```
fetch(".\Users\myName\OneDrive - myOrg\Documents\myFile.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Nothing is returning and I get that 404 error. I just want to console.log my json text. I can even convert it to a js file if that works better, but it didn't work here.

The file location actually reads:   C:\Users\myName\OneDrive - myOrg\Documents\myFile.json , so am I writing the URL wrong? Is there a way to pull from OneDrive that I am missing? Is it because I am using Codepen? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Since codepen is on the server, it can't reach local files on your computer. You'd have to upload the file first before you can read it on the server.

Comment: URLs to local files need to start with `file:///` … but standard security settings stop websites (including CodePen) from rifling through your hard drive and reading all your personal data).

Comment: Ah okay, sounds like I just need to run it on something else. Codepen just provided a solution to not having to download something on a work computer. They provide the service to upload files... for a fee